# Minipage side-by-side formatting

Tags: formatting

I have tried a couple of different commands to display my mini-pages side by side. but i can't figure out what the right syntax for it should be..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{1mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\flushleft

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[above] {$a$} (B) -- node[right] {$c$} (C) -- node[below] {$b$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage} 
\hfil 
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} 
\flushright
\begin{align*}
skalafaktor &= \frac{A}{a1} \\
skalafaktor &= \frac{7.3}{4.5} = x
\end{align*}

\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}


  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). It's best to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this case, try removing `\begin{minipage}{1mm}`.

Comment: if you are in vertical mode when you start a minipage, what follows will stay in vertical mode.  try putting `\leavevmode` or `\noindent` just before the start of the first `\minipage`, and don't leave a blank line.

Comment: Thanks guys. But it is still not working for me.
I have edited the code as erik suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the outer `minipage` with 1mm width?  Some things to note:

- The `\noindent` removes the standard paragraph indent.
- The `%` after the first `minipage` removes the interword space that would otherwise have been placed between the two minipages. Without this you'll get an overfull `hbox`.
- The vertical "anchor" of both `minipage`s have been set to `c`, so they are aligned vertically by their centers.
- `skalafaktor` has been placed in the `\text` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[above] {$a$} (B) -- node[right] {$c$} (C) -- node[below] {$b$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth} 
\flushright
\begin{align*}
\text{skalafaktor} &= \frac{A}{a1} \\
\text{skalafaktor} &= \frac{7.3}{4.5} = x
\end{align*}

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

You could also drop the `minipage`s altogether, and place the equations in a `node`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[above] {$a$} (B) -- node[right] {$c$} (C) -- node[below] {$b$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\node [right] at (2.5cm,0) {%
$\begin{aligned}
\text{skalafaktor} &= \frac{A}{a1} \\
\text{skalafaktor} &= \frac{7.3}{4.5} = x
\end{aligned}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just a pre made code i found. I still have a lot to learn here ;)

Comment: I was just about to post what you added in the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

If using `minipage`s, LaTeX will align the baseline of the `tikzpicture` with the first line of the `array`. I assume you want the equations vertically centered, which you can achieve a couple different ways.
(1) Use `\adjustbox` to vertically center both `minipage`s.
(2) Forget about using `minipage` and do everything in TikZ (as in the accepted answer).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\adjustbox{valign=c}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[above] {$a$} (B) -- node(c)[right] {$c$} (C) -- node[below] {$b$} (A);
\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
}
\adjustbox{valign=c}{%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} 
\flushright
\begin{align*}
skalafaktor &= \frac{A}{a1} \\
skalafaktor &= \frac{7.3}{4.5} = x
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]
\coordinate [label=left:$C$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$A$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$B$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[above] {$a$} (B) -- node[right] {$c$} (C) -- node[below] {$b$} (A);
\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);

\node [right=2 cm of c]{$
   \begin{aligned}
   skalafaktor &= \frac{A}{a1} \\
   skalafaktor &= \frac{7.3}{4.5} = x
   \end{aligned}
$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]